# Vuetify package css overrides application's css

Tags: css, vue.js, meteor, vuetify.js

Hopefully this is a newbie question.

I am working on integrating vuetify into an existing vuejs web SPA application in a few screens. The application uses  [purpose ui](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://themes.getbootstrap.com/product/purpose-website-ui-kit/&ved=2ahUKEwiChcqglIbmAhUNKKwKHfT-C10QFjACegQIEBAI&usg=AOvVaw3DdjUQELc1SdcFMV4uCfdO) for it's css and styling. After integrating vuetify into the application we see that the site now has the style of vuetify.

How can I ensure that vuetify's styling is only restricted to the specific vuetify controls on the few screens, that those controls are used on?

**Update 1:**

**index.js**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) 
{
  import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';
}
```

**index.html:** `meteor-bundled-css` line below should include the vuetify.min.css in the bundled css file but I don't see the css constructs in the bundled file, though the website is now a material ui\Vuetify website now.

```
<head>
  <link type="text/css" href="/css/purpose.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meteor-bundled-css /> 
</head>
```

Comment: Can you please specify how you import vuetify? Are you using webpack,.. etc.?

Comment: Thank you @A1rPun, I am using MeteorJs (and therefore I do not have to muck with webpack and such)., I import vuetify css in the index.js file. I have added an update in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to workaround this issue by removing Vuetify and adding BootstrapVue in the project, wrt to the BootstrapVue, Bootstrap css files, instead of adding the css files in the index.js file, I added the same to the client folder so it could be bundled\minified by Meteorjs itself.